# What is the single equation for a helix?

Tags: geometry, parametric, implicit-function

Is there a way to describe a helix not by its parametric form

$$ x=R\cos(t) ,\ y=R\sin(t) , \ z=ht , $$

but by a single equation like you can for a sphere with $ r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 $?

Also the same question for a 3-dimensional tube that follows a helix curve.

Comment: I got $x^2+y^2=R^2$ as best attempt

Comment: For the helix, I think you need at least 2 equations, hence: $x^2 = \sqrt{R^2-y^2} = \cos \left( \frac{z}{h} \right)$

Answer (score 0):

We can have asymmetric equation in terms of x, y and z:

To get such equation consider equation of a straight line in three dimension in form of symmetric:

$\frac{x-x_0}m=\frac{y-y_0}n=\frac{z-z_0}l$

To get parametric equation we can write:

$\frac{x-x_0}m=\frac{y-y_0}n=\frac{z-z_0}l=t$

$x=mt+x_0$, $y=nt+y_0$, $z=lt+z_0$

Clearly reverse procedure gives equation of line in terms of x, y and z. We apply this procedure to parametric equation of helix:

$x=R \cos(t)\Rightarrow t=\cos^{-1}\frac xR$

$y=R\sin (t)\Rightarrow t=\sin^{-1}\frac yR$

$z=ht \Rightarrow t=\frac z h$

Therefore symmetric equation for helix can be:

$\cos^{-1}\frac xR=\sin^{-1}\frac yR=\frac zh$